# How can I render an HTML table in a block?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

i have created a module for showing third party API data

here is some data returned from that API

```
{"ObjectId":43,"ObjectName":"MEGA MELA","ObjectTitle":"Event Created by API","ObjectDescription":"NEW EVENT BY API","ObjectLabel":"","ObjectTypeId":33,"MaxFieldsExpected":5,"ObjectValueType":null,"ObjectControlType":"","IsDeleted":true,"CreatedDate":"2019-05-22T07:56:03.767","CreatedBy":null,"EditedDate":null,"EditedBy":null,"DeletedDate":null},{"ObjectId":44,"ObjectName":"Event x11","ObjectTitle":"Event Created by API","ObjectDescription":"NEW EVENT BY API","ObjectLabel":"","ObjectTypeId":33,"MaxFieldsExpected":5,"ObjectValueType":null,"ObjectControlType":"","IsDeleted":true,"CreatedDate":"2019-05-23T00:33:50.7","CreatedBy":null,"EditedDate":null,"EditedBy":null,"DeletedDate":null}]}
```

i have created a custom module to show some of  this data in a block

this is my module directory hierarchy , module directory name is `apihtml`

```
 -apihtml 
    -src
      -Plugin
        -Block
          -rest.php   

    -apihtml.info.yml
```

as you can see there are just two files
  `apihtml.info.yml` and `rest.php`

here is `apihtml.info.yml` content

```
 name: Third Party Api Data with html
    type: module
    description: 'This is for showing rest data in ui with html'
    package: Custom
    version: 8.x
    core: 8.x
    dependencies:
      - node
      - block
```

and here is `rest.php` content

```
   <?php

/**
 * @file
 */
namespace Drupal\apihtml\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;

/**
 * Creates a 'Foobar' Block
 * @Block(
 * id = "AntShow with html formatting",
 * admin_label = @Translation("Ant Show & HTML"),
 * )
 */
class rest extends BlockBase {
 public function build() {
    /** @var \GuzzleHttp\Client $client */
    $client = \Drupal::service('http_client_factory')->fromOptions([
      'base_uri' => 'http://myApiPath',
    ]);



       $response = $client->get('objects/events');


    $dec = Json::decode($response->getBody());



    $items = [];


foreach ($dec as $d) {
    foreach ($d as $ins) {  
  $items[] = $ins['ObjectName'] ;

    }
}


         return [
      '#theme' => 'item_list',
      '#items' => $items,

    ];

  }
}
```

here by using `array`  `Key` `ObjecName` i am able to show object name in block

here is the block OutPut

MEGA MELA
Event x11

but i want something more
i want to show this API returned data in the tabular form   means the `array key` should be the `header`  of the `data` value data will be in `rows`

like this

```
   ObjectId  | ObjectName | ObjectTitle           | ObjectDescription | ObjectLabel | ObjectTypeId | MaxFieldsExpected | ObjectValueType | ObjectControlType | IsDeleted | CreatedDate | CreatedBy | EditedDate |  EditedBy
    43        |  MEGA MELA |  Event Created by API | NEW EVENT BY API | ..............................................................................
```

in this Drupal block all the data displayed has to be returned  in `build` function in `rest.php` file

this is the code which shows data returned by api in tabular format

```
     foreach ($dec as $d) {
  ?>
    <table>
<?php foreach ($d as $ins) { ?>
<tr>
<?php
 foreach ($ins as $key=>$value) {  
   echo "<td><h3>".$key."</h3></td>";
 } ?>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php
 foreach ($ins as $key=>$value) {  
   echo "<td><h3>".$value."</h3></td>";
 } ?>
</tr><?php
} ?>
</table> <?php
}
```

But i am not getting how can i put this code in `build` `function` of `rest.php` to show tabular data  in the `block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the table theme type to do this.  In your build section, return a render array that includes this:

```
return [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows' => $rows,
];
```

Where header is an array of strings and rows is an array of row value arrays.

Some reference items I found:

[New render element #type 'table'](https://www.drupal.org/node/1876710)

[Render arrays](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/render-arrays)